# A button that toggles its own background-color

Tags: android, button, background-color

I'm new to android so the question might seem very noob. My goal is to have a button that on click, change its own background color to red if it's currently green, change to blue if it's currently red, and green if blue.

I have a button:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="toggleColor"
        android:text="@string/foo" />
```

In MainActivity I have:

```
public void onClickCard(View view) {
    if (view.getBGColor == green) {
        view.setBGColor(red);
    }
    // ...so on
}
```

I don't know how to get the current color of my button. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, declare these fields,

```
    private enum ColorCodes {
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE,
        YELLOW
    }
```

//I assume you have red colour by default in your xml

```
 private ColorCodes colorCodes = ColorCodes.RED;
```

Then do something like this:

```
public void onClickCard(View view) {
        switch (colorCodes) {
        case RED:
            view.setBackgroundResource(blue);
            colorCodes = ColorCodes.BLUE;
            break;
        case GREEN:
            view.setBackgroundResource(yellow);
            colorCodes = ColorCodes.YELLOW;
            break;
        case BLUE:
            view.setBackgroundResource(red);
            colorCodes = ColorCodes.RED;
            break;
        case YELLOW:
            view.setBackgroundResource(green);
            colorCodes = ColorCodes.GREEN;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
  public void onClick(View view) {

            ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();                    
            int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();                   

            if (colorId==Color.GREEN) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this, use [LevelListDrawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) you can in use [getBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground%28%29) to inspect the level of the background and change according to that.